# foreignKey undefined belongsToMany association

Tags: sequelize.js

I have 2 tables Manufacturer and TabsTemplate. These 2 tables are associate using many-to-many association. However, I'm getting an error while running the app on the server.

**Migration - ManufacturerTabs**

```
return queryInterface.createTable('ManufacturerTabs', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      ManufacturerId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        references: {
          model: 'Manufacturers',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      TabsTemplateId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        references: {
          model: 'TabsTemplates',
          key: 'id'
        }
      }
    });
```

**Model - Manufacturer**

```
   Manufacturer.associate = function (models) {
        Manufacturer.belongsToMany(models.TabsTemplate, { through: ManufacturerTab});
      };
```

**Model - TabsTemplate**

```
TabsTemplate.associate = function(models) {
    TabsTemplate.belongsToMany(models.Manufacturer, { through: ManufacturerTab});
  };
```

**Error**

```
warning ../../../../../../package.json: No license field
$ cross-env DEBUG=express-sequelize node ./bin/www nodemon app.js
sequelize deprecated String based operators are now deprecated. Please use Symbol based operators for better security, read more at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:242:13
/Users/rdagli/Desktop/Projects/Internal/Brand Compass/Production/postgres-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js:266
    if (!this.through.model.rawAttributes[this.foreignKey]) {

                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'TabsTemplateId' of undefined
    at BelongsToMany.injectAttributes (/Users/rdagli/Desktop/Projects/Internal/Brand Compass/Production/postgres-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js:266:42)
    at Function.belongsToMany (/Users/rdagli/Desktop/Projects/Internal/Brand Compass/Production/postgres-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/mixin.js:53:17)
    at Function.TabsTemplate.associate (/Users/rdagli/Desktop/Projects/Internal/Brand Compass/Production/postgres-server/models/tabstemplate.js:13:18)
    at Object.keys.forEach.modelName (/Users/rdagli/Desktop/Projects/Internal/Brand Compass/Production/postgres-server/models/index.js:29:19)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rdagli/Desktop/Projects/Internal/Brand Compass/Production/postgres-server/models/index.js:27:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rdagli/Desktop/Projects/Internal/Brand Compass/Production/postgres-server/routes/index.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rdagli/Desktop/Projects/Internal/Brand Compass/Production/postgres-server/app.js:9:14)
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
```

Comment: Don't define the FK on the model, let the `belongsToMany` do the job with `as:`. Something like this:  `Manufacturer.belongsToMany(models.TabsTemplate, { through: ManufacturerTab, as: 'Manufacturer'});`. This also will help youh when you try to `include` the model on a query.

Comment: @Ellebkey I tried that, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Could be a silly statement but you have to do a migration or delete the table and run again sequelize. And erase the fileds on the model. Just with the associations.

Comment: @RahulDagli You should use `through: "ManufacturerTab"` in association or define `ManufacturerTab` model and pass it as model: `through: models.ManufacturerTab`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53564526/10728931). If you want use additional properties, use second declaration. Also you should pass `foreignKey` and `otherKey` in association declaration, [see](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-belongsToMany).